# How to apply css to custom content created in alfresco web quick start

Tags: css, alfresco

I have created a custom content model in alfresco. Also i have updated web quick start so that custom content type comes in create content dropdown in document library. When i click on custom type, a form appears with all metadata fields along with content editor.

Using this i can create content but it is plain content without any css. I want to replicate a website, hence i need same styles as of target website but i am not finding on how & where to apply custom styles to my content in web quick start to mimic the website?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems alfresco web quick start was not designed with this requirement in mind.

Nevertheless, if what you want is "css routed through workflow and replication", a quick hack to implement it goes like this:

- Upload your file in the editorial site. Make sure it is not of mimetype text and not in a folder matching the regular expression `/(css|js|img|images|swf)/.*`. The mimetype is important to avoid a behaviour firing and setting the type to article. Avoiding the regex match is to make sure webstart tries to pick up the resource from the repo. A file `sample.dss` in the `root` folder should work fine.
- Set mimetype of `sample.dss` to `Plain Text`. Use the Edit Properties Dialog in share.
- Put the folloing code in `head.ftl`

  <#assign cssId=webSite.rootSection.getAsset("sample.dss").id?replace(".*/","","r")>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${url.context}/asset/${cssId}" type="text/css" media="screen" />